# Epub.js - Phonegap not working because of blob URI

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, blob, epub

I'm using Epub.js library to render a .epub file in a Phonegap project.

The file gets fetched and unzipped correctly, but then the screen is displayed blank if running in WebView (Works perfect in Desktop and in android browser (Chrome app)).

Debugging, I see that the `iframe` where the epub should be loaded doesn't work, as `iframe.onload` never gets called. The URL he's trying to access is
`blob:file%3A///85a6ce73-2b5f-430e-a908-26a7d3d830e4`, so I'm guessing that could be the reason... Cordova doesn't accept `blob` URI schemes.

However, I don't know any workaround... I'm completely stuck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. The answer to all "Cordova doesn't accept URI" is always "Whitelist"

With the whitelist plugin I had in my config file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

However, debugging i saw that the `blob:/file://...`uri was getting blocked in shouldAllowNavigation. Then I tried with:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation origin="*" />
```

But! it still didn't work. Debugging a bit more, I saw that the WhitelistPlugin if you add a `*`it doesn't allow everything, but only `http://`, `https://`and `data:`. Finally, adding:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="blob:*" />
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Also, just in case it's helpful for someone, while I was testing, I tried downloading the .epub file from a server and extracting it in the filesystem (/data/data/package/...) and accessing it from there. For some reason, accessing local files with XHR Requests returns `status: 0`, like it failed, but the response is there. I had to edit epub.js file `EPUBJS.core.request`method to accept responses if `this.response` is set (instead of expecting `this.status`to be `200`).

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do the same thing. I was able to download book using File-Transfer plugin but I can't open it. How did you do that part?

Comment: In my case, I downloaded the .epub using the `content-sync` plugin. This plugin is to download and extract zips (and .epub is a zip), so this plugin was perfect. Anyway, when you get the path to the extracted directory (p.e. "/data/data/package/files/files/my-book") just call Epub.js by `ePub("file://" + path_to_dir)`. If it fails, check out this `this.status == 200` check and... the whitelist, maybe I touched something from that to make it work.

Comment: Trying to replicate your success, but no luck. All points are verified - blobs are whitelisted, epub.js checked and looks like authors already fixed this issue. But now I have a kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork code=1 error... Will be very appreciated for any ideas

Comment: See that the cordova-plugin-whitelist is supported only on 4.x.
Is there a similar plugin for 3.x version or another way of achieving the same?