# Phonegap/Cordova 3.6 - Download of file through blob:file

Tags: file, cordova, blob, phonegap-build

We have an app using Phonegap 3.6.3 and built with *Phonegap build*.
As part of this app, we need to download a file onto the device of the user. The file might be a .pdf, an image or any binary file.

We hope to download the file with a blob:file link in the app, and not use a plugin such as file-transfer.

The file is converted from Base64 data and a Blob object is created. 
An objectURL is generated through window.URL.createObjectURL() and this is added to the href attribute of an a element.

The DOM contains the following

```
<a href="blob:file%3A///cf2e336c-8c10-4e54-9e99-26f7d5a0115f" download="1.jpg" style="display: none;"></a>
```

On desktop, this works without problems, but in the app packaged with cordova 3.6.3 it just fails silently.

I suspect it's related to whitelist functionality in cordova. 
In the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31945728/250787 others have solved the same problem with the cordova-plugin-whitelist. 
Unfortunately, this plugin is only for cordova 4.0+

I've tried using the access origin element, but none of the statements appears to have an effect

```
<access origin="blob:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="blob:*"/>
```

I already have a access origin to limit traffic to the main backend system of the app

```
<access origin="https://mobilbackend.mycompany.com/*"/>
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: @dpamas, are you really using *Phonegap Build*, the cloud-base service by Phonegap? And are you also using *Phonegap CLI*, the command-line version that runs locally on your machine?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 yes, I am really really using the cloud based Phonegap build service :) Therefore, I am not able to do any changes directly into generated android classes and am limited to the configuration options they expose in the config.xml file. I'm not using the Phonegap CLI.

Comment: @dpamas, apparently you have some misunderstandings about how Cordova/Phonegap works. Almost anything you need done can be done with a plugin. If you feel like creating classes, you can create your own plugins. [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html). Answer in just a bit.

Comment: @dpamas, Your post confused me because Phonegap Build does not have a version 3.6.5 [listed as being avaiable](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_multi_platform). I must assume your post had a typo. Now to be clear, you MUST set the version of your compiler, else you will get the latest version - which is currently `cli-5.2.0`. And another factor is that if you are using the latest *compiler version* you are required to use the new `whitelist` system. In addition, both Google and Apple are now requiring such filters.

Comment: One another point, the *Tools Release* version is different from the "pinned version", which might be the version you are quoting. You can set the *compiler version* via the [`phongap-version` preference](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_multi_platform). FWIW: I have tutorial to get you through the `whitelist` mess.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 you're right I screwed up on the version. Using 3.6.3 through config <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />

Have made a plugin so am aware of the process, but also know that some answers for cordova questions recommend going into the Activity class for each operating system (which should not be done normally, and is not possible through phonegap build versions)

Comment: Okay. If you need more help, just leave a message in this thread. I'm usually on SO three (3) or four (4) times a day.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 still need help :) Only workaround I see is to use the file or file-transfer plugins, but I had hoped to avoid that

Comment: @dpamas, file-transfers require the `whitelist` plugin. It would be best if you clarified your question before I give you the answer. Make sure to respond on this thread, so I see you have made changes. The answer is easier than you think. Clarifying your question will help other who see this in the future. TIA Jesse

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 longest comment thread ever :) file-transfer is unrelated to this concrete question. Not sure what's more needs clarifications

Comment: @dpamas, on the first line, you write *We're trying to download a file from a an app using (...)"*. if you are not using "file-transfers", please clarify.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 clarified question

Answer (score 2):

Okay. `blob:` requires special additions to the `whitelist` system, of which you seem to have an incomplete understanding _OR_ are using outdated documentation. I can tell because `launch-external="yes"` has been removed from use.

- You will need to use both the `whitelist` plugin and add a `<meta (...) />` entry into the header of our `.html` pages.
- You need to implement the [*cordova-plugin-whitelist*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist).
- This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
  [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

**NOTE DOING THIS WILL MAKE YOUR APP INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html` and every `.html` page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src * blob:; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

I have added `blob:` into the `CSP` definition. However, this just opens up the app to allow the `blob:` URL. It is still not clear to me what you mean when you say "download the file", as `blob:` is not transport protocol. It is only intended to define a [type of file](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blob).

I also recommend reading this [whitelist worksheet](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md), make sure to read [9. CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md#csp)
Lastly, if you want to continue this discussion, please continue on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: Thanks for the background information, has helped me in getting a better overview of how the various pieces fit together. Unfortunately, the suggestions you have does make binary data added to blob:file anchor persisted on the devices (in the same way as on browser on the desktop). CSP is likely not involved as the chrome dev tools have never shown any warnings of CSP item blocking (and adding the meta had no effect on the isse). My guess is that Cordova now let's links with blob:file through, but the WebView of the OS ignores them. Will look at other approaches to achive the same

Comment: Hmm. You are missing two more pieces. My notes on [Webview](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md), the library use to render the screen using HTML5 and CSS. Make sure to read the part with Paul Irish. It might be in my notes on [Webview Alternatives](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview-alternatives.md). Please continue discussion on Google Groups.

Comment: @dpamas, Sorry. I had a headache last night, I think yours was the last thing I answered. You are using an outdated version of Cordova/Phonegap. We are now using 5.x. 3.x was using the old webview library. 5.x uses the Webkit library. I will never work with 3.x. [Upgrade to 5.x](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/23/phonegap_520_now_on_build). NOTE: I still don't know what you mean by "download a file".

Answer (score 0):

So I created a solution that saves the blob and then opens it with the system viewer.
If you want it to be saved in a different location see: [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files).

By choosing this location you can have it download straight to the desired location.
If you open the file with the system viewer then there is often an option for the user to save the file.

```
// previously blob is defined as file, 
//and file name is saved in data.FileName

var savedFile;

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function( dir ) {

    dir.getFile( data.FileName, { create:true }, function( file_ ) {

        savedFile = file_;
        saveFile();

    });
});

function saveFile(str) {
    if( !savedFile ) return;

    savedFile.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.write( file );
        cordova.plugins.disusered.open( savedFile.nativeURL );
        console.log( "file " + savedFile.nativeURL + " opened" );

    }, function( e ){
        throw( 'createWriter Error error' + JSON.stringify( e ) );
    });
}
```

This uses the plugins of:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
cordova plugin add cordova-open --save
```