# Downloading a pdf blob to device in Cordova Android App

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a program where I want to save a pdf blob in a android device.
This is server side code inside a callback which receives pdf data as 'result'.

```
var file = new Blob([result.data], {
          type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8;'
        }); 
        return file;
      });
```

At client side, the following code works in chrome debugging browser and pdf is successfully downloaded. However on device I get the following error :

```
 11-18 18:13:27.255 10504-10707/? D/FileTransfer: download blob:file:///e9088aac-8525-4071-9280-164a6e15c22e to file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/loanContract_11-10-2016_9-29-59-715.pdf
 11-18 18:13:27.255 10504-10707/? E/FileTransfer: Unsupported URI: blob:file:///e9088aac-8525-4071-9280-164a6e15c22e
```

Here the data in window.URL.createObjectURL(data) is the file blob returned by server. [Phonegap/Cordova 3.6 - Download of file through blob:file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356724/)  didnt help me in solving the problem.

```
var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    $scope.content = data;
                    a.href = fileURL;
                    a.download = fileName;
                    a.click();
                    console.log("Inside parent function");
                    $scope.fileName = fileName;

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (dirEntry) {                   
                download($scope.fileURL, dirEntry.toURL()+'Download/'+ $scope.fileName) ;
             }, function () {} );


  var download = function ( uri, fileURL) {
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            fileURL,
            function (success) {
                console.log(success);
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }, true)
    };
```

If i give a url which sends a pdf file as HTTP response and I provide the API's URL as the parameter uri to cordovaFileTransfer.download, then the pdf gets saved.
Kindly help me saving this bob as a pdf on the device.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the file by [requesting the file system](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) and then download it from your server with [fileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download). After completing the download call the FileOpener (which will open a pop up where to choose from apps like Adobe Reader). Note: Make sure to include the FileTransfer feature via CLI/Terminal:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
```

- Navigate to your project folder
- Open CLI/Terminal and type in:

  cordova plugin add
     https://github.com/don/FileOpener.git
- After successful download and storage of your file on the device (see
  above) you open it with:
  window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.example.application/document.doc")
  or the appropriate path on iOS.